# Jest: Error: Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am implementing jest to test my React app and have set up a simple test on a utility function I have, but I am getting the error:

> Error: Your test suite must contain at least one test.

Have checked my implementation, and I think all is correct - could someone take a look got me?

The file structure for the test and the function is as follows

```
- __tests__
  -- sumObjectValues-test.js
- utils
  -- sumObjectValues.js
```

`sumObjectValues.js` is as follows:

```js
const sumObjectValues = (obj, identifier) => {
    return obj
        .map((el) => { return el[identifier]; })
        .reduce((prev, next) => { return prev += next; }, 0);
}

export default sumObjectValues;
```

And `sumObjectValues-test.js`:

```js
   const obj = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "item": "Tesla Model S",
        "amount": 85000
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "item": "iPhone 6S",
        "amount": 600
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "item": "MacBook Pro",
        "amount": 1700
    }
];

const identifier = "amount";


jest.unmock('../client/utils/sumObjectValues'); // unmock to use the actual implementation of `sumObjectValues`

describe('sumObjectValues', () => {
    if('takes an array of objects, each with amount values, & sums the values', () => {
        const sumObjectValues = require('../client/utils/sumObjectValues');
        expect(sumObjectValues(obj, identifier)).toBe(87300);
    });
});
```

Then I have `"test": "jest"` in my package.json scripts, but get the following error:

```
FAIL  __tests__/sumObjectValues-test.js (0s) ● Runtime Error
  - Error: Your test suite must contain at least one test.
       at onTestResult (node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestRunner.js:143:18) 1 test suite
failed, 0 tests passed (0 total in 1 test suite, run time 13.17s) npm
ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Thanks all :)

**N.B.**: Was a typo in the `it`, but after fixing I am getting a new error:

```
FAIL __tests__/sumObjectValues-test.js (321.763s) ● sumObjectValues ›
it takes an array of objects, each with amount values, & sums the
values - TypeError: sumObjectValues is not a function at
Object. (__tests__/sumObjectValues-test.js:27:10) 1 test
failed, 0 tests passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 344.008s)
npm ERR! Test failed. See above for more details.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Node.js doesn't support ES2015 modules](http://es2015-node.js.org/) (yet). Try changing `export default sumObjectValues` to `module.exports = sumObjectValues`.

Comment: Ahh, of course, I can add the babel jest module to try to sort that, will give it a go! Thank you :)

Comment: Ah man, this is painful.. I think I need to go sleep. It has run now I have installed babel-jest, but I am getting a new error:  FAIL  __tests__/sumObjectValues-test.js (321.763s)
● sumObjectValues › it takes an array of objects, each with amount values, & sums the values
  - TypeError: sumObjectValues is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/sumObjectValues-test.js:27:10)
1 test failed, 0 tests passed (1 total in 1 test suite, run time 344.008s)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: I'm just spitballing since I haven't used ES2015 modules in Node yet but have you tried using the [`import` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) instead of `require`?

Comment: Yes! You beauty! Thanks Mike, that was it, appreciate the help :)

Comment: Lol! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

```js
if('takes an array of objects, each with amount values, & sums the values', () => {
```

should be

```js
it('takes an array of objects, each with amount values, & sums the values', () => {
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think to write tests later, 
You can just ignore them with this

```
test.skip('skip', () => {});
```